# Robocopy Only Output Copied Files

Tags: powershell, synchronization, powershell-3.0, robocopy

I have the following Robocopy command. Currently it outputs all directories it is traversing during the mirror but I only want it to output what actually got synced from source to destination. I'm not seeing a "only show differences" option in [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

```
robocopy "C:\inetpub\example.com" "Z:\D Drive\Projects\example.com\Web\example.Web" /mir /xd "C:\inetpub\example.com\wp-content\mu-plugins\example-network" "C:\inetpub\example.com\wp-
content\plugins\example" "C:\inetpub\example.com\wp-content\themes\example" ".git"
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course I figured it out right after I posted the question. Here is my new command. The **/fp /ns /ndl** options did the trick.

```
robocopy "C:\inetpub\example.com" "Z:\D Drive\Projects\example.com\Web\example.Web" /mir /fp /ns /ndl  /xd "C:\inetpub\example.com\wp-content\mu-plugins\example-network" "C:\inetpub\example.com\wp-content\plugins\example" "C:\inetpub\example.com\wp-content\themes\example" ".git"
```

#### Meaning of switches

From [SS64 entry](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html):

```
/FP : Include Full Pathname of files in the output.
[...]
/NS : No Size - don’t log file sizes.
[...]
/NDL : No Directory List - don’t log directory names.
```